# Excel 2010 If Cell = N/A then value from another cell, if not N/A then value from a different cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I need a formula in cell D1 to read

```
if cell A1 = N/A and B1 = 0 or < 1 
    then use value from B1
if not N/A and <> 0 or > 1 
    then use value from C1
```

Any suggestions?

I would like to add another condition to =IF(AND(B2<>"N/A",OR(C2<1,C2=0)),I2,C2).
I need to add another OR clause stating B2<>"N/A" and C2>0, then L2 has to be 0. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is pretty close to what you want in cell D1 but your conditions for choosing C1 are not clear.

```
=IF(AND(A1 <> "N/A", OR(B1 = 1, B1 =0)),B1,C1)
```

N/A would need to be the text "N/A" for this to work

If N/A is the Excel error Type #N/A then you should use

```
=IF(AND(Error.Type(A1) <> 7, OR(B1 = 1, B1 =0)),B1,C1)
```

as suggested by chuff in the comments

Comment: @Kristian, if the NA were the actual Excel error value #N/A, you could test for it by using the worksheet function `ERROR.TYPE`. It takes a value as a literal or cell reference, and returns a number corresponding to the type of error (#N/A's number happens to be 7). For more information, see this **[Microsoft documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/error-type-HP005209079.aspx)**

Comment: @Kristian, the 1st way was correct. It is N/A, not #N/A. I have another question: I would like to add another condition to the existing formula that I have =IF(AND(B2<>"N/A",OR(C2<1,C2=0)),I2,C2). I need to add another OR clause stating B2<>"N/A" and C2>0, then L2 has to be 0. Is this possible?